# Insufficient privileges for dbms_transaction.commit_comment

Tags: oracle, distributed-transactions

Trying to set up a scenario of record locks due to pending distributed transactions.

Goal: get some rows into DBA_2PC_PENDING for training purposes and forcing commits/rollbacks/purging entries etc.

According to Database Administrator's Guide (12c)

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/ds_txnman.htm#ADMIN12285

in section *35.9 Simulating Distributed Transaction Failure*

the following code should accomplish what I need:

```
DECLARE
    l_tran_id VARCHAR2(200);
BEGIN
    l_tran_id := dbms_transaction.local_transaction_id(true);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('l_tran_id: ' ||l_tran_id);
    abc.package1.proc1@DB2 (  parm1 => 'XXX' );
    COMMIT COMMENT 'ORA-2PC-CRASH-TEST-5';  
END;
```

But when I run this, I get *ORA-01031: insufficient privileges* with error pointing to line holding the commit.

If I change to `COMMIT COMMENT 'hooray';`

I don't get error, but of course I don't get my results of a pending transaction.

What privileges is it complaining about?

Comment: I don't have access to distributed databases to test this but  [the documentation states](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/ds_txnman.htm#ADMIN-GUID-94CB1DFF-1100-4D3B-8E83-902CA85B5551) we need FORCE TRANSACTION or FORCE ANY TRANSACTION to manually commit a transaction. I'm wondering if the same privilege is required to manually fail a transaction?

Comment: My understanding is that the force transaction only applies to forcing rolling back or forcing commit AFTER transactions are in the pending phase. But I will see if that's our problem and report back. Thanks for the tip